# How can find the regex for separating strings

Tags: regex, linux

I have this file

```
xorg-fonts-misc-1.0b-1
Xorg-font-bitstream-75dpi-1.0.0-2.i386
Xorg-font-bitstream-100dpi-1.2a-2.arm
Other-Third-Party-1.2.2-1-any
```

i want to separate and want output like this

```
xorg-fonts-misc-               1.0b-1
Xorg-font-bitstream-75dpi-     1.0.0-2.i386
Xorg-font-bitstream-100dpi-    1.2a-2.arm
Other-Third-Party-             1.2.2-1-any
```

I tried this

`-[^a-zA-Z][0-9\.\w-]+[^a-zA-Z][\w-]*?[\d\w]*\n`

Comment: Instead of saying "I want output like this", can you explain what you want your output to be? What are the allowed characters in the first/second part for example.

Comment: And can you explain where your output is coming from?  Because you may be able to *generate* output in the format you want without needing to parse anything.

Comment: Parsing those as you want is going to be tricky, because names may contain numbers that are not versions (e.g., `Xorg-fonts-bitstream-100dpi`) and version numbers may contain letters (e.g., `tzdata-2012j`).

Comment: So Peters answer will fail on the - interpreting your input as some kind of package descriptors - fairly common case of 'gtk2-2.8.i386' for example.

Comment: @SecOe fair point, updated my answer to not require a dash in the second half of the output.  And it is true that if you're using a packaging tool, you can probably get an output almost exactly like that with some specific options

Comment: How do you decide that `75dpi` is part of the package name and not the version number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will put your text into two matching groups.  I put spaces between the two groups, but you can put tabs or whatever else in there if you want

```
/^(.*?)((\d[a-z]?\.)+.*)$/\1    \2/gmi
```

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fS5uX3) is a great place to test out regexes.  That link has the regex and your test input, and gives a full explaination of how the regex works

Comment: thakns buddy , that worked. Although it may not work in some cases but ur solution will do